# When serving static files in Hapi.js how do we ensure the correct mime type is sent?

Tags: node.js, mime-types, hapi.js

We are trying to **serve static** (JS/CSS/etc) **files** in our **Hapi.js** project and need to confirm we are getting the correct Mime Type.

#### Code (simplified)

examples/staticfiles.js

```
var Path = require('path');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server  = new Hapi.Server();
var port    = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.connection({ port: port });

server.views({
    engines: {
        html: require('handlebars')
    },
    path: Path.join(__dirname, 'views')
});

server.route([  
  { path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    config: {
      auth: false,
      handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply.view("index");
      }
    }
  },
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/public/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: Path.normalize(__dirname + '/public')
        }
    }
  }
]);

server.start(function(){
  console.log('Static Server Listening on : http://127.0.0.1:' +port);
});

module.exports = server;
```

examples/views/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Serving Static Content in Hapi.js 8.2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Open the Console...</h1>
    <script src="/public/hello.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

examples/public/hello.js

```
console.log('hello (should print in the console)');
```

As per the documentation documentation: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files

Visiting the url in the browser: **http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/hello.js** we see:

[image: loading a js file prints the code in the browser - does not run]

and when we `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/public/hello.js`

we see:

[image: curl -v public/hello.js]

Which suggests that the *correct* content-type is being sent to the client.

#### Notes:

- Code on GitHub if you want to help debugging:
  https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-hapi/tree/master/examples/staticfiles.js
- Node.js version: **v0.12.1**
- Hapi.js version: **8.2.0**
- run using: `node examples/staticfiles.js`

***Thanks*** in advance for your help!

Comment: Got a few replies on twitter. The mime type is correct.

Comment: Try using the mimos module which Hapi references in the docs.

Comment: Good shout @BingeBoy will be using mimos - https://github.com/hapijs/mimos next time we need to identify mime types. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here. Hapi serves the static file with the correct mime type (application/javascript). You can see this in the output of curl, and you can see it also in the browser:

[image]

When you visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and open the console, you can see that `console.log` is executed.

[image]